# How do I display the right answer when the wrong answer button is selected?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui-button

```
@objc func rightAnswer(sender : Button) {
        
    if AnsNumber == 0 && sender.tag == 0 {
        
        sender.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.03577814337, green: 1, blue: 0.0007592695236, alpha: 1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
}

@objc func colorButton1(sender : Button) {
    
    if AnsNumber == 0 && sender.tag == 0 {
        
        sender.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.03577814337, green: 1, blue: 0.0007592695236, alpha: 1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
    
    else {
        
        rightAnswer(sender: button)
        
        sender.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.8514541941, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.01176470611, blue: 0.5607843399, alpha: 1)
            
        }
    }
}
```

`rightAnswer()` method is checking which button is being clicked by the user and is also checking if the button that's pressed by the user contains the right answer and the colour will change green if the condition is met and if the condition is not met it will change red.

`colorButton1()` method is checking for similar thing except there are four buttons and each one is assigned a tag. this is checking for the button that's tag is equal to 0.

Basically `colorButton1()` method will change the button colour to red when the answer is wrong I also require to show the button with the right answer in green.

Comment: This is confusing, both the question and the code. I guess you have two buttons and one should turn red and the other one green? And regarding the code, in `colorButton1` you call `rightAnswer` when the condition is false but in `rightAnswer` you check the exact same condition again so of course it will still be false and nothing will happen in `rightAnswer`. _Edit: I now see you call `rightAnswer` with a different argument but where does that variable `button` come from?_

Comment: basically I'm developing a quiz based game and when the wrong answer is picked the button color of that button which is picked but the user would turn red but at the same time, whatever the right button based answer is should turn green to indicate to the user this is the right answer for the question.

Comment: Ok but you need to explain your code much better, what is this `button` variable you send, what is AnsNumber,  why compare with tag = 0? Please edit your question with more information.

Comment: Yeah Sure will do.